# Two Sum Algorithm - Using Find Index - Javascript Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question**

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

*But, I specifically want to use the findIndex() to solve this. The problem is we need two indices to add together! Not just one.*

```js
function twoSum(arr, target){

let relevantArr = [];

let newArr = arr.slice(0,);

function test(){

return newArr.findIndex(added);

}

function added (a, b) {
  a + b == target;

}


return relevantArr
}



console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
```

Help appreciated, if you know a way to make this work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on the array items and try to find its complement to get the target. If the complement is not found, `findIndex` returns -1 and you check the next one.

```
function twoSum(arr, target){
    for(let i = 0, len = arr.length ; i < len ; ++i)
    {
        // try to find an item so that its sum with arr[i] is equal to the target
        let j = arr.findIndex(item => item + arr[i] == target); 
        if(j != -1)
        {
            // we found the element, we can return the answer
            return [i, j];
        }
    }
}
console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)); // [0,1]
console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 18)); // [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if you *want* to use `findIndex`, then its return value can never be enough, as it is only one index. You could use a "side effect" and use another variable to store the second index. For finding the second index, don't use `findIndex` again, as that is overkill. Use `indexOf`, and make sure it only scans the part of the array that comes *after* the first index (using the second argument of `indexOf`):

```js
function twoSum(arr, target) {
    let j = -1; // Needs to be accessible by the following function:

    function added(val, i) {
        // modify the variable outside of this function scope:
        j = arr.indexOf(target - val, i + 1);
        return j >= 0; // true if success
    }

    // findIndex will modify j, which we add to the pair
    return [arr.findIndex(added), j]; // will be [-1, -1] when not found
}
console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)); // found
console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 100)); // not found
```

The `added` function is now a "dirty" function, because it alters a variable in the outer scope. But this is closest to what you were trying to do.

A plain `for` loop would be more called for (together with the `indexOf`). And for large arrays, you would benefit from first creating a map, so you don't need a linear look up within that loop, but a constant one.